# How to recognize outside sound using iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone

I want to find out sound intensity using iphone. I searched in google and got this info http://www.future-apps.net/Decibel_Meter/Decibel_Meter.html, so now my question is how to enable Decibel meter and get readings. Is there any api in iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You can `peakPowerForChannel` and `averagePowerForChannel` from the [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder?language=objc) API.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-decibels-from-the-ios-microphone) describes how to get the decibels using AVAudioRecorder. It's actually pretty simple.